# do expected near then

Tags: if-statement, lua

I was recently asked by a friend for help with writing a program in lua what finds perfect squares, so I drew up this:

```
print ("Select your maximum number")
x = io.read()
y=1
z={}
a=1

while y * y ~= x and y < x / 2
    then do
        y = y + 1
end
if y * y = x
    then do
        z[a] = x
        a = a + 1
end
x = x - 1
```

To test the program, I added

```
print z[1]
```

to the end. When I went to test this program, I got the following error in line 8:

*do expected near then*

Do was near then. Could someone tell me where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You could really benefit from reading the manual: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.4

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of syntax errors in that code. The first is that `while` is written as `while foo > bar do`, whereas `if` uses the syntax of `if foo > bar then`.

The other error is that in your `if` statement, you have `if y * y = x then`. The logical equal to operator is `==`, so it should be `if y * y == x`.

Answer (score 4):

In Lua, it's `while <expr> do <code> end` and `if <expr> then <code> end`. Also, equality test is `==`. So your code should be:

```
while y * y ~= x and y < x / 2
    do
        y = y + 1
end
if y * y == x
    then
        z[a] = x
        a = a + 1
end
x = x - 1
```